# Swift/IOS/CoreData: How would I define a var as an enum type in an auto-generated CoreData class?

Tags: swift, core-data

Swift/IOS newbie here...

I have a CoreData entity with an Int16 property. I'd much rather use an enum to represent this property, but I'm using auto-generated entity classes (those the inherit from NSManagedObject), and I can't directly change the type for a property, because it would get deleted if the file is re-generated.

Is there an elegant solution to this?

EDIT: just realized I can't even use the dirty solution because my enum cannot be translated to an Objective-C primitive type, and therefore can't be used in an object that inherits from NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't incredibly hard, but it is harder than you would want it to be.

First, IMO, abandon the "if the file is re-generated" part. While I try to mess with the auto-generated files as little as possible, in my experience (at least prior to Xcode 8 where everything changes and I haven't really explored Core Data yet), letting Xcode regenerate those files is not worth the headaches. Generate it once, and then tweak it as you need. This is controversial, and is not absolutely necessary, but in my experience has worked best.

So saying that, in `MyObject+CoreDataProperties`, just comment out the definition. For example, from one of my files:

```
//    @NSManaged public var id: NSNumber? // programmatic
```

Yes, this is ugly, but it has saved me a lot of trouble (I'll explain my older approach below, which doesn't do this). Even if you *do* regenerate the file, the errors will be pretty obvious, so they're not too hard to fix.

Once you've done that, just reimplement your type like:

```
var myProperty: MyProperty? {
    get { return MyEnum(rawValue: primitiveValueForKey("myProperty") }
    set { setPrimitiveValue(newValue.rawValue, forKey: "myProperty") }
}
```

You of course could make this non-optional by crashing if it fails, or returning a default, and you could use something other than `rawValue` here. Whatever is appropriate.

Note that `myProperty` is not `@objc` (and can't be dynamic; and so can't be KVO). So you could use `valueForKey` rather than `primitiveValueForKey` here if you wanted.

But Rob, I really, really want to let my files be regenerated (and Xcode 8 is going to push us that way anyway, so stop telling us to do things that will break some day). Fair enough.

You do it by naming your backing property something different than your public property. So in CoreData the property is called "propertyValue" and that's an `NSNumber` or `Int16` or whatever. And then `property` is the good one. This is often a somewhat annoying naming convention because it muddies you code completion. What you'd like to call this is `_property` in Core Data or `__property`, but that's not legal. So what some people do is call it `zProperty` or `zzProperty` so all the backing properties sort to the end.

It's possible that Xcode 8 also has some other powerful tool to help better with this. I'm not aware of one, but I've only begun to explore Core Data in Xcode 8.